# AWS Redshift - Format all rows into a json file

Tags: sql, formatting, amazon-redshift

Any information about formatting SQL table in reshift to a JSON file. I see SQL syntax doesn't work on here. It says Syntax error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SQL or Redshift might not help you here. Even if you find a way for it, it'll be too complex. Try scripting or writing a code for this. PySpark and their relevant libraries/modules might help.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Redshift [UNLOAD command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) can only output in Fixed-Width or Delimited (eg CSV) format.

You could either convert the output from the UNLOAD command, or use/write a program that calls Redshift via SQL and saves the output in the desired format.